# Telerik: get upload file's name from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a Telerik file selector for uploading like this:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Upload()
            .Name("attachments")
    %>
```

then in javascript, I want to check if the filename is in correct format. But I don't know how to get the file name out of the upload box. This

```
var upload = $find("attachments");
```

gives me null. And this

```
var upload = $get("attachments");
```

gives me a strange object that I don't know how to move on with. Anyone has experience with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get the upload object by using something like `$("#attachments").data("tUpload")` as the documentation says. I would think you would want to check this in the `Select` event. Look at this for good examples, specifically the `getFileInfo` function: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload/clientsideevents

Answer (score 1):

You can use client side events for this.

I used the onSuccess event and it was working fine. 
You should register the even like this (to telerik upload's html helper);

```
.ClientEvents(events => events
   .OnSuccess("onSuccess"))
```

and then in your javascript code;

```
function onSuccess(e) {
        switch (e.operation) {
            case "upload":
                console.log('upload --> ' + e.files[0].name);
                break;
            case "remove":
                console.log('remove --> ' + e.files[0].name);
                break;
        }
    }
```

You can also have some other useful information from event argument (e). You can check it with tools like firebug.

You will probably need to use onSelect event like this but i think it's usage is same way the onSucsess works.

As Jisaak pointed out [telerik documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/upload/clientsideevents) has good information about it.